# how to get payment information on Magento?

Tags: php, magento, payment, orders

I have to export the orders to a file, here is my code to go through the orders:

```
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('status', 'ncm'))
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute' => 'status', 'eq' => 'complete')
        )
    );

    $order = $orders->getFirstItem();

    //print_r($order);
    //exit;
    //foreach($orders as $order){
    $id = $order->getIncrementId();

    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $method = $payment->getMethodInstance();

    print_r($payment);
    //}
```

I need to print some information about the payment
like the method, the amount, how many months it was split, if was credit card, i need the reutrning id of the transaction and so the list goes on

how can I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it will be

```
   $payment = $order->getPayment();
```

It will retrieve the current order payment instance.

Comment: I am already using that code, but I can't seem on how to retrieve those specific info. Would help me figure it out?

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw that code. Please, try $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation(); - this is payment + transaction info

Comment: $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getPaymentInfo();

Comment: For some payment modules `$order->getPayment->getMethodInstance()->getData()` doesn't work. If you need to know the custom methods, try `var_dump(get_class_methods(get_class($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance())))` to get a list with all possible methods. In my case they're called `getAccountBankname` or `getAccountBLZ` ... it's a bit tricky, but I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 19):

```
//Get Payment
$payment = $order->getPayment()

//Get card type
$payment->getData('cc_type')

//Get Payment Info
$payment->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
$payment->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();

//Get Credit Card info
$payment->getMethodInstance()->getCardsStorage()
$payment->getMethodInstance()->getCardsStorage()->getCards() //array()
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the ID (number) of method too?

Answer (score 5):

To get the method code only it's far safer to use

```
$order->getPayment()->getMethod();
```

Skipping instance object which can generate exception if the payment method was uninstalled.