# Magento: Increase "Qty" upon cancel a shipped order

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm on Magento 1.7.0.2. I'm using "Cash On Delivery" as my payment method.I'll tell you exactly the steps That i follow on any order. When an order is placed(Qty decreased 1 item), I create a shipment for it and if customer paid the order grand total price. I create an invoice for that order.

My problem, If an order is placed(Qty decreased 1 item), I create a shipment for this order. If the customer refused to pay, I open this order and "Cancel" it and on this case the "Qty" doesn't increase so How can I make it increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to R.S as he helped me more & more.

I followed all instructions on R.S's reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/13330543/1794834 and I've only changed the observer code. Here is the observer code that worked with me on Magento 1.7.0.2.

```
$curr_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

foreach ($order->getItemsCollection() as $item) 
{ 
    $productId  = $item->getProductId();
    $qty = (int)$item->getQtyOrdered();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $stock_obj = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
    $stockData = $stock_obj->getData();
    $product_qty_before = (int)$stock_obj->getQty();
    $product_qty_after = (int)($product_qty_before + $qty); 
    $stockData['qty'] = $product_qty_after;
    /*
     * it may be case that admin has enabled product add in stock, after product sold,
     * he set is_in_stock = 0 and if order cancelled then we need to update only qty not is_in_stock status.
     * make a note of it
     */
    if($product_qty_after != 0) {
        $stockData['is_in_stock'] = 1;
    }else{
        $stockData['is_in_stock'] = 0;
    }

    $productInfoData = $product->getData();
    $productInfoData['updated_at'] = $curr_date;
    $product->setData($productInfoData);
    $product->setStockData($stockData);
    $product->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**If order status is Processing**

Create a custom module with observer for 'order_cancel_before' (see example @ [Change Magento default status for duplicated products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677971/change-magento-default-status-for-duplicated-products) change `<catalog_model_product_duplicate> to <order_cancel_before>`

since `<order_cancel_before>` is not defined in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

You could override/rewrite order model class see e.g http://phprelated.myworks.ro/how-to-override-rewrite-model-class-in-magento/

In your local module do

```
public function cancel()
{
    if ($this->canCancel()) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('order_cancel_before', array('order' => $this));
        $this->getPayment()->cancel();
        $this->registerCancellation();

        Mage::dispatchEvent('order_cancel_after', array('order' => $this));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**Or you could create a new method increaseProductQty() in your model and copy the code below into it (this way you would not need an observer).  Then replace the line Mage::dispatchEvent('order_cancel_before'... with $this->increaseProductQty()**

In your observer method (pseudo code)

```
$curr_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

foreach ($order->getItemsCollection() as $item) 
{ 
    $productId  = $item->getProductId();
    $qty = $item->getQty();

    // you need to check order status to make sure it processing
    //$order->getStatus() (assuming you are canceling entire order)
    //$order->getPayment();

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $stock_obj = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->load($product_id);
    $stockData = $stock_obj->getData();
    $product_qty_before = (int)$stock_obj->getQty();
    $product_qty_after = (int)($product_qty_before + $qty); 
    $stockData['qty'] = $product_qty_after;

    $productInfoData = $product->getData();
    $productInfoData['updated_at'] = $curr_date;
    $product->setData($productInfoData);
    $product->setStockData($stockData);
    $product->save();
}
```

If you have issue with updating stock see [Set default product values when adding new product in Magento 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289371/set-default-product-values-when-adding-new-product-in-magento-1-7)

Reference http://pragneshkaria.com/programatically-change-products-quantity-after-order-cancelled-magento/

**If order status is Pending**

Take a look at System > Configuration > Inventory

**Set Items’ Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled** — Controls whether products in pending orders automatically return to the stock if orders are cancelled. Scope: STORE VIEW.

Read more @

[How to Manage Magento Store Inventory?](http://www.magedevelopers.com/articles/magento-tutorials/magento-store-inventory-management)

[ADMIN: System → Configuration → Inventory Tab](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_config/edit/cataloginventory)

Comment: your solution works well when the order on Pending status but my problem is canceling an order on Processing status (as I shipped it)

Comment: Thank you very very much and I'll try your code but I want the above code to work only with "Cash On Delivery" payment method.

Comment: Check the payment method type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669099/how-to-get-payment-information-on-magento

Comment: Really I appreciate your effort with me. I have another question Please How can I check order status to make sure it processing

Comment: On the config.xml what is the method name??

Comment: $order->getStatus() (assuming that you are canceling the entire order which i think your doing)

Comment: xml <method>duplicateProduct</method> ... observer public function productDuplicate(Varien_Event_Observer  $observer)

Comment: as the event order_cancel_after so the $order->getStatus() will get the new status which will be "canceled" not "processing". Please advise

Comment: Take a look at all the observer http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/... it doesnt seem like there is a before cancel, so take a look at app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php you may need to extend cancel() ... take a look @ http://phprelated.myworks.ro/how-to-override-rewrite-model-class-in-magento/ and put this Mage::dispatchEvent('order_cancel_before', array('order' => $this)); after the if statement OR you could just put the above code in this section without creating a observer

Comment: After Adding the observer code and canceling the order, the Qty became zero. Please advise

Comment: Take a look at my update code... 'order_cancel_before' should contain the order info before it's status or qty change

Comment: I'll create a new method increaseProductQty() so what is the code I'll replaced for `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();`

Comment: Try $this->getAllItems(), $this->getId() take a look at canCancel() in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

Comment: Great, but how can we allow cancel function to execute?

Comment: If you override/rewrite the order model class as shown in the link then it will execute instead of app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

Comment: It didn't work with me here is my code

//config.xml
http://pastebin.com/98wisM20

//NileCreations_ExtendOrderCancel.xml
http://pastebin.com/1fMuQiCG

//Order.php
http://pastebin.com/KEZWDp2f

Comment: Your config is not complete... replace this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677971/change-magento-default-status-for-duplicated-products with your <global> and update the <modules> section

Comment: Did you add your custom module xml file to app/etc/modules/NileCreations_ExtendOrderCancel.xml? As in example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677971/change-magento-default-status-for-duplicated-products

Comment: Yes, I added it on that path. here are all the path pp/etc/modules/NileCreations_ExtendOrderCancel.xml /app/code/local/NileCreations/ExtendOrderCancel/Model/Order.php /app/code/local/NileCreations/ExtendOrderCancel/etc/config.xml

Comment: You are missing the closing '</config>' in config.xml ... http://pastebin.com/YLNTFKSr

Comment: I'm so sorry for missing `</config>`. I have test the new module using the method increaseProductQty() and the Qty became 0 which is wrong value so I'll the Observer method.

Comment: I have tried the observer method and I got the same result Qty became 0. Please advise

Comment: I think the problem on qty as I have mailed myself the $product_qty_before I got 0 and $qty I got nothing and $product_qty_after I got 0

Comment: I got it and I'll update your answer. Thanks for your support and your time.