# Magento - How can I put shipped items back in stock when the shipped order returned?

Tags: magento

I like to add the products back to the inventory when i am cancelling the order from processing status (order shipped).

currently magento automatically update the qty when you cancel a order in pending status. I want the same to be done during cancel from processing status.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330140/magento-increase-qty-upon-cancel-a-shipped-order

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a creditmemo.