# Magento: Retrieve payment information with Authorize.net gateway

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using Authorize.net payment gateway in my magento based shopping cart. It is Authorize Only, which means I first authorize the card, an after shipping product to customer I captures the amount.

Authorize paygate stores information like cc_exp_month, cc_exp_year inside "additional_information" field in table sales_flat_order_payment in serialize form.

Is there any method in magento to simply retrieve these values (cc_exp_month, cc_exp_year) from additional_information column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the next 2 lines will do the trick:

```
$ccExpMonth = $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation('cc_exp_month');
$ccExpYear = $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation('cc_exp_year');
```

Of course $order is instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Order.

For reference you also can check: [how to get payment information on Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669099/how-to-get-payment-information-on-magento)

Comment: I have seen that post earlier and tried the same way as you suggested, but it is not fetching the values like this. I have checked and found that authorize.net stores these information inside an array "authorize_cards" so if we will try to fetch them directly, they are not coming. For this I have applied a foreach loop and then getting values, but not sure this is logical and right way to do or not?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any method in magento to simply retrieve these values (cc_exp_month, cc_exp_year) from additional_information column?

No, there isn't.  You need to drill into the additional_information array.  Here's a method I added to retrieve the cc_type value.  It can easily be adjusted to return all the data or just another piece:

```
public function getCcType(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment $payment)
{
    if(count($payment->getAdditionalInformation()))
    {
        foreach($payment->getAdditionalInformation() as $auth_cards)
        {
            foreach($auth_cards as $ac_id)
            {
                if(isset($ac_id['cc_type']))
                {
                    return $ac_id['cc_type'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$order_id = 113
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
```

If info is stored cc_exp_month and cc_exp_year

```
$ccExpMonth = $order->getPayment()->getCcExpMonth();
$ccExpYear = $order->getPayment()->getCcExpYear();
```

If info is stored in Additional Info

```
$ccExpMonth = $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation('cc_exp_month');
$ccExpYear = $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation('cc_exp_year');
```

Comment: R.S - This way it is not fetching values, for details please see my comment added in ceckoslab's answer.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.. do you have any info in cc_exp_month and cc_exp_year (same table) this is where my cim module store it

Comment: What column in the db is 'authorize_cards' in? do print_r($order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation()-getData()) and see what result you get